# Python max() and min() values for bool

Tags: python

In python interpreter,

```
min(True,False)==False
max(True,False)==True
```

is assured by design?

Comment: Yes, but code that relies on that fact is probably... oddly designed.

Comment: `min(a,b) == (a and b)` and `max(a,b) == (a or b)` for booleans `a`, `b`.

Comment: @larsmans Might be a use case, but `all()` and `any()` are better suited for this.

Comment: @glglgl: I wasn't suggesting a use case, I was pointing out that the OP should be using `and` and `or` when dealing with booleans. And yes, `all` and `any` when working with sequences of them.

Answer (score 12):

`True` is equal to `1` and `False` is `0`

Answer (score 3):

It seems, at least in CPython, `bool` subclasses `int`. Therefore, you can do:

```
>>> abs(False)
0
>>> abs(True)
1
```

and:

```
>>> False < True
True
>>> True > False
True
```

I guess `max` and `min` work on the comparison operator:

```
>>> cmp(False, True)
-1
>>> cmp(True, False)
1
>>> cmp(False, False)
0
>>> cmp(True, True)
0
```

Comment: `bool` should subclass `int` in all Pythons.  See [PEP 285](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Good call. I guess I just got lazy there, because I *was* contemplating checking the docs, but, you know, it's friday, the sun is shining and my new sunglasses wanted me to go get some ice cream ;)

Answer (score 3):

In python 2.x, this is not guaranteed, as you can overwrite True and False:

```
>>> False = 23
>>> max(True, False)
23
```

But if you do not assign to True or False, it is guaranteed by Language Design that Booleans subclass int with values 0, 1, yes. (and in py3, True and False are reserved words, so  you cannot do the above)

Comment: This is a somewhat pathological example; the object that is denoted by `False` by default is still equal to `0`: after `false = False; False = 23`, `false == 0` (or `bool(0) == 0`) still holds.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the doc](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values),

> In numeric contexts (for example when used as the argument to an arithmetic operator), they behave like the integers 0 and 1, respectively.

So, yes, it is assured.

Comment: The notion of a "numeric context" isn't particularly well-defined, though, and `max` and `min` work on any ordered type, so I'm not sure if they qualify.

Comment: But I think that this part ensures that `-1 < False < True < 2`.